# After installing Visual Studio 2017, I'm unable to debug smart device project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017, just shortly after it was released (March 2017).

When I go to debug my smart device project in VS 2008 I get a error message dialog that just says "The operation could not be completed". , .

Here is a list of what I've observed:

- The project output successfully deploys
- no error message is displayed in the output window in Visual Studio
- when I go to Debug=>Attach to Process and open the Transport drop down, it doesn't contain Smart Device like it usually does.
- ProcMon shows that devenv is maintaining a open connection to the device on port 5355

What I've tried:

- I tried debugging on multiple emulator types and devices that I know have worked in the past.
- I tried creating an new solution with the default smart device project.
- I tried deleting all the files in %localappdata%/Microsoft/CoreCon/1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25132/visual-studio-2017-install-breaks-sql-server-manag.html): The cause is an error in the registration of the type library for this component.

To fix this issue, you can either:

Open a command prompt with administrator privileges and execute the following command:

```
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{6A1A7D39-8449-4287-8EF0-CE256582C940}\8.0\0\win32 /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\coloader80.tlb"
```

Alternatively you can execute:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\coloader80.dll"
```

The correct registration will be included in future versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to use Visual Studio to debug its self, I got the following error message

```
"A Visual Studio DLL, coloader8O.dll, is not correctly installed. Please
repairyour Visual Studio installation via ‘Add or Remove Programs’ in
Control Panel.
If the problem persists, you can manually register coloader8O.dll from
the command prompt with ‘regsvr32
“%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft
Shared\VS7Debug\coloader8O.dll”.
```

I was able to fix the issue by following some instructions I found on [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25605/installing-vs2017-unregisters-coloader80dll.html) which involves changing the regestry values at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{6A1A7D39-8449-4287-8EF0-CE256582C940}\8.0\0\win32` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\\coloader80.tlb`